# CakePHP 3 - Parent association

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, parent, cakephp-3.0

I have an existing database (can't make changes) with the following tables:

**Category**

- id
- name

**Category hierarchy**

- child_id
- parent_id

I want to create a checkbox list of (parent)categories for one categorie. I have something like this:

**Categorie table**

```
$this->belongsToMany('Categorie', [
        'foreignKey' => 'child_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'joinTable' => 'category_hierarchy'
    ]);
```

**Categorie controller**

```
$parent = $this->Categorie->Categorie->find('all')
        ->select(['Categorie.id', 'Categorie.naam']);
```

Now I can create a checkbox list, only the correct categories are not checked. So I do the following:

```
$categorie = $this->Categorie->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Categorie']
    ]);
```

When I do this, the whole form becomes empty. **Is it possible to say that it contains parent categories?** Something like this:

```
$categorie = $this->Categorie->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['ParentCategorie']
    ]);
```

Comment: Your final containment (`ParentCategorie`) should be correct, if you change the `belongsToMany` association to match. Note that you'll need to add `'class' => 'Categorie'` to the association, since the normal default will not apply now. You may find there are other related changes required elsewhere, like `Categorie->Categorie` won't make sense any more.

Comment: What do exactly do you mean with 'match'?

Comment: `$this->belongsToMany('ParentCategorie', [...`

Comment: $this->belongsToMany('ParentCategorie', ['className' => 'Categorie', ...]); fixed it.